# Delete query from pg_stat_statements in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, statistics, postgresql-14

I need to use pg_stat_statements, I have read about pg_stat_statements_reset() which can discards all statistics. But is there a function which can discards statisctic of one custom query? Can it be removed automatically?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [that's possible](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html#id-1.11.7.39.8), just reset the stats for this specific userid, database and query id:

```
SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset(userid Oid, dbid Oid, queryid bigint);
```

Check your stats for the right userid, dbid and queryid.

Comment: But thats is not in version 11?

Comment: @yuoggy: check the extension

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens worked a charm 

Answer (score -2):

There are no options to delete statistics for a specific object.